# Perforce P4 sync, need to checkout  "just" part of the mapping in the clientspec

Tags: perforce

**Perforce repo:** //repository

//repository has directories like "Block_A" , "Block_B". 
Block_A has directory "development". So is Block_B

**Perforce clinet spec:** //repository/...    //my_client_spec_dir_mapping/my_development/...

If I do "p4 sync" whole of "//repository" will be in "//my_client_spec_dir_mapping/my_development". I "only" want everything under "//repository/Block_A/development" to be in "my_clientspec_dir_mapping/my_development"

I do "NOT" want to change the client spec.

Tried **"p4 sync -n //repository/Block_A/development/..."**. Didn't work. How do I go about it.

Comment: What error did you get on the partial p4 sync command ?

Comment: If you said 'sync -n' and it didn't work, that's because the '-n' flag tells sync to preview the operation, but not actually perform it. Try removing the '-n'.

Comment: Why can't you change the client spec? Depending on the settings, you can still see the full repository, etc.

Comment: @BryanPendleton You could put that down as the answer :)